# proper way to write this timed jquery function

Tags: jquery, timer, settimeout, setinterval

I want this function to initiate every 4 seconds. is there a way of putting them in an array and call it every 4 seconds rather than this way. Also, this way has a delay of 16 seconds before it actually begins. Thanks in advance.

```
setInterval(function() {
     setTimeout(function () {
         $j('.menu2').trigger('click');
         }, 0000);

         setTimeout(function () {
         $j('.menu3').trigger('click');
          }, 4000);

         setTimeout(function () {
         $j('.menu4').trigger('click');
          }, 8000);

         setTimeout(function () {
         $j('.menu1').trigger('click');
          }, 12000);

}, 16000);
```

Answer (score 1):

<s>Try this out</s>

```
setInterval(function () {
        var time = 0;
        for (i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                $j('.menu' + i).trigger('click');
            }, time);
            time += 4000;
        }
    }, 16000);
```

**Update**

http://jsfiddle.net/6NwLG/1/

```
setInterval(function () {
        var time = 0;
        for (i = 1; i < 5; i++) {

            test(time, i);
            time += 4000;
        }
        function test(time, id) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                $('.menu' + id).click();
            }, time);
        }
    }, 16000);
```

Comment: hmmm nearly works. i think the number needs converting to a strong maybe?

Comment: You shouldn't have to. Do you get any errors running this code?

Comment: cool, that works. But it still has a dealy of 16 seconds at the start. I want it to start after 4 seconds...

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).delay(12000, function() {
    var interval = setInterval( function() {
       time = 2000;
       m = 1;
        for( i =0; i < 5; i++) {
       setTimeout( function() {
           $('.menu'+m).trigger('click');
           time = time+2000;
           m = m+1;
       }, time);
    }
    }, 4000);
});
```

​

Comment: thanks but this gives an error "Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'delay' "

Comment: hey man i checked this code for more than ten times and it does not show any error!

Comment: i'm sorry but this just isn't working for me :(
thank you so much for helping though